# Sql Server 2008 r2 sp2 out of memory error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one query with 21072 individual update statements in SSMS. I am using sql express r2 sp2. I am updating only one varchar(255) text field with short strings < 100 chars. I only get partway (3344 executions) through the statements before I get the error.

"There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query"

I have 16GB physical memory on Win7-64 Ultimate. This should be a trivial operation with no errors.

This seems like a bug in the software or I have a default memory setting in Sql express that must be changed.

I apologize for errors in advance and thank you for answering.

Product details:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: "This seems like a bug in the software" - whilst possible, which is more likely that or a problem with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express is limited to 1 CPU and **1GB of RAM**.

Without more specific details it is hard to help you further. Suggest you post your actual TSQL.

**Update**: you are saying that you have 21072 individual update statements, run as a single batch.  Try putting some `GO` 's  in there... e.g.

```
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Abalone' WHERE ItemID = 3; 
GO
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Absidia capillata' WHERE ItemID = 4; 
GO
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Acacia' WHERE ItemID = 5; 
GO
etc..
```

That assumes you are not trying to run as a single transaction, of course. (Which you don't appear to be)

Comment: Here is the first of 21072 lines:   UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Abalone' WHERE ItemID = 3; This is very typical of all of them. Do you really need all of my lines? My post is down minus 1. WTF? It's a really good question.

Comment: I am nowhere near that limit.

Comment: @Paul: post your TSQL in your question; not as a comment here.

Comment: Minegot you want 21072 lines of the same thing? Here are the first 7: UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Abalone' WHERE ItemID = 3;
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Absidia capillata' WHERE ItemID = 4;
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Acacia' WHERE ItemID = 5;
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Acetaldehyde' WHERE ItemID = 6;
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Acrothecium robustum' WHERE ItemID = 7;
UPDATE Item SET ItemName = 'Acrylic' WHERE ItemID = 8;
What more do you need? I am now at -2, and my rep is hard won, I appeal to the community!

Comment: @ Mitch: you are correct and I didn't know this. Adding the GO fixed the problem. I salute you in my descent in the ratings to 0 or lower... the stack is a harsh mistress.